# Sort a column in a Google Sheets automatically from Z-A by column name

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Spreadsheet where I import data in a certain sheet (Sheet2). In "Sheet2" I have more columns (depending of the imported data, in some situation I have more and In some situation I have less) but some columns names are always the same like "timestamp" in my exemple from the link.

I need some QUERY or FUNCTION to automatically sort that COLUMN by the column name "timestamp"...not by COLUMN letter, because in some situation "timestamp" is in other COLUMN letter.

EXEMPLE SITUATION: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/172RDg2yrk04mciL7Tmi3PWBBV8AY7AII43jFX_HcB64/edit#gid=0

I try manually, but do not help me, I also try to "Create Filter" but also not working. I need something do sort that column automatically after is imported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know which formula you're currently using, but you can do this workaround that should work in any case:

```
=LET(q,put your current formula here,
QUERY(q,"SELECT * order by Col"&XMATCH("timestamp",INDEX(q,,1))&" desc"))
```

Comment: Have you tried my option?, if you need from Z-A, you need to use "desc" instead of "asc"

Comment: I use this formula: `=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("MYID", "SHEET!1:1000"), 
"SELECT Col" & 
JOIN(", Col", 
MATCH(
{"timestamp"},
IMPORTRANGE("MYID", "SHEET!1:1"),0)))`  i tried to put my formula in "put your current formula here" but also not working....for sure is something that I dont get it...:(

Comment: With your answer I do some workaround and now it's working, BIG THANKS!!!

Answer (score 1):

Sorting in descending order

Put a row of checkboxes on row one.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast("Entry");
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "Sheet0" && e.range.columnStart < 17 && e.range.rowStart == 1 && e.value == "TRUE") {
    e.source.toast("Gate1");
    e.range.setValue("FALSE");
    const sr = 3;
    const col = e.range.columnStart;
    const sh = e.source.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
    var vs = sh.getRange(sr, 1, sh.getLastRow() - sr + 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    if (vs.map(r => r[col - 1]).flat().every(e => !isNaN(e))) {
      e.source.toast("numeric");
      vs.sort((a, b) => { return b[col - 1] - a[col - 1] });
    } else {
      e.source.toast("lexicographically");
      vs.sort((a, b) => {
        if (a[col - 1] < b[col - 1]) return 1;
        if (a[col - 1] === b[col - 1]) return 0;
        if (a[col - 1] > b[col - 1]) return -1;
      });
    }
    sh.getRange(sr, 1, vs.length, vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
  }
}
```

Demo:

[image]

Sort By Column Name

```
function sortByColumnName(colName) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  var [hs,...vs] = sh.getRange(1, 1, sh.getLastRow() -  1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var col = {};
  hs.forEach((h, i) => { col[h] = i + 1 });
  var column = col[colName] || 1;
  Logger.log(column);
  if (sh.getRange(2, column, sh.getLastRow() - 1).getValues().flat().every(e => !isNaN(e))) {
    vs.sort((a, b) => { return b[column - 1] - a[column - 1] });
  } else {
    vs.sort((a, b) => {
      if (a[column - 1] < b[column - 1]) return 1;
      if (a[column - 1] === b[column - 1]) return 0;
      if (a[column - 1] > b[column - 1]) return -1;
    })
  }
  sh.getRange(2, 1, vs.length, vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
}
```

Comment: Ok. But how will the checkbox row will help me? Because the COLUMN that I need to sort it by NAME is always in a new sheet...only the COLUMN NAME REMAIN the same

Comment: Try the second one.

Comment: It checks the entire column if they are all numbers then it sorts it numerically if they are not all numbers then it sorts them lexicographically

Comment: I didn't really understand what you wanted at first so I just did what I thought might be useful.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `MATCH` to find the column index for the timestamp heading and then pass that along to a `QUERY` or `FILTER` and `SORT`. You already have an example provided by Martin using `QUERY`, so here's an example using `FILTER` and `SORT` (which might matter if some of your rows contain images). I don't know how many rows or columns you're dealing with so naturally adjust values where appropriate.

```
=SORT( FILTER( Sheet2!A2:J500, Sheet2!A2:A500 <> '' ), MATCH( 'timestamp', Sheet2!A1:J1, 0 ), FALSE )
```

Docs:

- SORT - https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093150
- FILTER - https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197
- MATCH https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378

The last parameter at the end of the example is the sort order, the `is_ascending` parameter of the sort function, a 0/false value is descending and 1/true is ascending.