# Sort Google Sheet by certain column using Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a MASTERSPREEDSHEET(CHECK LINK) with 3 sheets or more in the future. In one of the Sheet(SHEET2) at the end of the day I import automatically some data.

QUESTION: I need some help to sort the SHEET2 by the column name "timestamp" (FK in my exemple). I need to make the sorting my latest date and after I import data from SHEET2 to SHEET1 the data must be sorted on SHEET1.

I know how to sort it based on the exact column position (FK)...but the problem is that, at each data I import data at the end of the day in the SHEET2 the position of the column with the name "timestamp" in not always the same (FK).

To be more precise, I need to sort Sheet2 by the "timestamp" column exactly as I would do it manually... but I need some function in Apps Script

LINK: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/172RDg2yrk04mciL7Tmi3PWBBV8AY7AII43jFX_HcB64/edit#gid=2053213612

I hope I make myself clear. Thank you very much!

Comment: About `I update the post. Thanks!`, thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill, again. From your updated question, where can I see the sample input and output situation you expect? I couldn't find it. I apologize for this.

Comment: You can see the situation in the LINK

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. From `You can see the situation in the LINK`, although I saw your provided Spreadsheet, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: In the Speedsheet that I provided you can see go to column FK...I need some script to sort that Sheet by that column name.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `In the Speedsheet that I provided you can see go to column FK...I need some script to sort that Sheet by that column name.`. Can I ask you about the details of it? I would like to correctly understand the current issue of your script and your goal. By the way, can you provide your current script?

Comment: @JamesN. I just want to clarify about your expected result. May I ask on your Sheet 1, is that how you want the result after the Script? or Were you looking to copy all of the rows along with the timestamp?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77040902/7215091

Comment: @Babanana
 First I want the Sheet2 to be sorted by column name "timestamp" and after the results goes tot Sheet1.

Comment: @Cooper
 I was thinking about that...but my Sheet2 is a dynamic Sheet, at the end of each day it is rewritten

Comment: @JamesN. Sorry I wasn't clear about my question. So you are looking for the data to be copied and sorted based on the timestamp so the latest first right? However I am asking if you are going to include all the data or just the timestamps? Additionally will you have multiple headers that says timestamp when you are importing data and the script have to detect that manually?

Comment: @Babanana Yes, I looking for the data to be copied and sorted based on the timestamp so the latest first right. From the Sheet2 I only include the "timstamp" and other 3 columns. I think the simple way will be to automatically sort the Sheet2 by the "timpstamp" and then I import data to Sheet1. Hope I make myself clear :)

Comment: I do apologize I still have no clear understanding of your expected result. Please add more defined information about your expected result. I highly suggest that you include it on your sheet.